# Django Rest Framework return a JSON file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django and Django REST Framework, I am trying to write a GET request which when called will return a JSON file located on the server. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
class MyView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        ...

        # I get a filepath to 'somefile.json'     
        my_filepath = "/Users/me/Desktop/somefile.json"

        ...

        # What do I do in order to return 'somefile.json'?    
        return Response(somefile.json)
```

**EDIT**

I do not want to return the contents of *somefile.json*. I want to return the file itself.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) help?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. `return FileResponse(my_filepath, 'rb')` did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `FileResponse` object as [described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects).